# Clear HashMap Values While Retaining Keys

Tags: java, hashmap

Is there a way to clear all of the values, while retaining the keys?

My `HashMap` is `<String,String>`, so should I just loop through and replace each `value` with a `null`? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: May I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: Sure. I have a file, similar to a csv. First I'll read in all of the Field Names, and set those as keys. Then, for each subsequent line, I'll set each field as a value, and do things. Then, I'll do it again for the next line. Some fields may be missing, though (will be a " ", so I want to make sure the data does not accidentally persist for the next line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Map#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.BiFunction-) if you are using Java 8+ :

```
map.replaceAll((k, v) -> null);
```

If not, looping over the `Entry`s will probably be the simplest way. From the link above the default implementation of `Map#replaceAll` is equivalent to:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
    entry.setValue(function.apply(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
```

Where function is the parameter, so you could do this:

```
for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    entry.setValue(null);
}
```

Comment: set null and remove are two different methods, the map array will grow if you add a bunch of null values

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it simple and collect the headers in a list or set then create a new HashMap at each line by looping over the list  instead of trying to recycle the same map.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
  map.put(key, null);
}
```